# How can I override the src tags generated by HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have multiple outputs with some hash in the name in my **Webpack** configuration and that is why I try to utilize **HtmlWebpackPlugin** to auto-generate the index HTML file which serves the SPA app. So far so good.

However, because I serve the SPA app from an MVC framework with a template engine; I want it to decide where the assets are located. That means, I have to modify the `<script>` tags put by the HtmlWebpackPlugin like:

From:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/app.js">
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('app.js')}}">
```

I read the docs and had an eye on the listed extensions but no luck. Is there any undocumented way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a plugin to achieve that. Here is the source code:

```js
function HtmlWebpackLaravelAssetPlugin(options) {}

HtmlWebpackLaravelAssetPlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {

        compilation.plugin(
            'html-webpack-plugin-after-html-processing',
            data => {
                data.html = data.html.replace(/(src\=\"public\/)(.*?)(\"\>)/gi, 'src={{ asset("$2") }}>')
            }
        )

    })
}

module.exports = HtmlWebpackLaravelAssetPlugin
```